# XMLHttpRequest not sending token (Laravel page expired)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Laravel and trying to send a form via `XMLHttpRequest`. It works but the request in the controller doesn't identify it as ajax. The form has a `csrf` input.

I've tried several things, right now my code looks like:

```js
...
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", FD.get("_token"));
...
```

But Laravel keeps sending a `419 | Page Expired` response.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting this information, barking at the wrong tree, or I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **X-Requested-With** header to your request and change your content header to **multipart** or **json** :

```
XHR.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", 'XMLHttpRequest');
XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'multipart/form-data'); // or application/json
XHR.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", FD.get("_token"));
```

Comment: Thanks, applying your solution seems an advance, but now in the response I get `CSRF token mismatch.`

Comment: I had to exclude the route from csrf verification to make it work, but I'm not sure that's the safe course.

Comment: i think you have make mistake in csrf parameter name ,see my edited answer @schrodigerscatcuriosity

Comment: Great! I had the line before but in trying so many things I deleted it. Thank you very much.